# How to convert txt file to jsoinl lines file for Hungarian char.?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, jsonlines

I have **`txt`** file that contians two columns (`filename` and `text`) the spreater during generating txt file is tab       example of input file  below :

`text.txt`

```
23.jpg   még
24.jpg   több
```

the expacted `output_file.jsonl`  type json line format

```
{"file_name": "23.jpg", "text": "még"}
{"file_name": "24.jpg", "text": "több"}
```

But I got issue with uincode or encoding format :

```
{"file_name": "23.jpg", "text": "m\u00c3\u00a9g"}
{"file_name": "24.jpg", "text": "t\u00c3\u00b6bb"}
```

it seems that dosent recognize hungarain spicial charchters `áéíöóőüúüű`  for both small and captial case

for example in resulting `*.jsonl` file it gives assci or differnt encoding `\u00c3\u00a9` code instead of the letter `é`

I wrote this small sript to convert `*.txt` file in Hungarain languge to `*.jsonl` in Hungarain too

```
import pandas pd 
train_text = 'text.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(f'{train_text}' ,header=None,delimiter='   ',encoding="utf8") # delimiter tab here 
df.rename(columns={0: "file_name", 1: "text"}, inplace=True)

# convert txt file to jsonlines 
reddit = df.to_dict(orient= "records")
import json 
with open("output_file.jsonl","w") as f:
   for line in reddit:
     f.write(json.dumps(line) + "\n")
```

My expactation `output_file.jsonl`  type json line format

```
{"file_name": "23.jpg", "text": "még"}
{"file_name": "24.jpg", "text": "több"}
```

Comment: As an aside, you may find that `df.do_json` does what you want without the extra code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump), `json.dump` includes a `ensure_ascii` flag. It's always puzzled me why it's `True` by default, but that's the thing that inserts Unicode escape sequences instead of using multibyte utf-8 encodings. It should be fine... other parsers should figure it out. But to fix the problem do,

```
f.write(json.dumps(line, ensure_ascii=False) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75594200/218663 by @tdelaney is great and I upvoted it. If you wanted to bypass the step of casting to a dictionary you could also do:

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([
    {"file_name": "23.jpg", "text": "még"},
    {"file_name": "24.jpg", "text": "több"}
])

with open("out.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file_out:
    df.to_json(file_out, orient= "records", force_ascii=False)
```

It is essentially the same "force_ascii" issue.

Comment: Thanks, @tdelaney  jonsg this also works. but in case reading the big text files with GB size with pandas it seems to miss some values. I don't know why like filename (111.jpg) it saves as (111.     p)
meanwhile, I have opened another issue for virtualization can you please take a look?

Comment: This is a great solution but should note that the original code wrote a bunch of small newline-delimited JSON strings (dicts in this case) whereas this solution writes a single JSON string with an outer list holding the dicts. Whatever consumes this file in the future needs to know the difference.

Comment: @MahmmoudAbedSuleiman - JSON encoders  / decoders shouldn't miss anything. If you could narrow this down to a small example where it happens - something that we could test - that would be interesting.